# Not Code Clean Up After Removing DTO and Service On JDL

Tags: jhipster

After the DTO and service of one entity are removed, the dto class is still there and is used in another dto. It is the same for its mapper class. And the service class is there although it is no longer used by the controller. It is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because JHipster does not know whether you have modified these files and so it is conservative just in case you haven't committed your changes.

The only time JHipster cleans up obsolete files is during upgrade process because it refuses to run if your workspace has uncommitted changes and so it knows it's safe to delete files that you can retrieve from git history.